# How can I match incomplete single quotes while ignoring apostrophes?

Tags: php, regex

I am trying to match sentences in a text where a closing single quote mark is missing (I'm using PHP). The simple solution to this is:

```
~'[^']*$~
```

but that doesn't cope with apostrophes.

For example, in these sentences

```
'This is incomplete
'This isn't incomplete.'  
I said 'this is incomplete.   
I said 'this isn't incomplete but I was wrong.
```

I want to match all of them except for the second one, which is not missing its closing quote.

I've tried using negative lookahead to rule out correctly closed quotes (eg where followed by a space, a period (or other end-of-sentence punctuation) or the end of the line, but I can't get it right.

(Apostrophe cases to overlook would be any where the apostrophe is followed by s, l, r, d or v - let's ignore the fact that plural possessives can be followed by a space, as that's making things too difficult.)

Comment: *let's ignore the fact that plural possessives can be followed by a space, as that's making things too difficult.* I thought it was too difficult already. :-)

Comment: One-line sentences?

Comment: Well, I think `preg_match("~^(?:[^']|\b'\b)*(?!\b'\b)'(?:[^']|\b'\b)*$~", $s)` might work for you. See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHxncs/2).

Comment: I'm with @Andreas I think. Is there an actual use case for this? In most cases assuming this is user input, it's up to the user to get the language / grammar right, not for the application to decide they're wrong. Even more so if you're leaving out plurals. What about contractions?

Comment: @Jonnix the use case is for identifying common errors in a text, so it's absolutely the point of the application to decide they're wrong. But I'm also pragmatic about the endless counterexamples one gets with natural language (hence plurals).

Comment: Thank you @Wiktor - that's really helpful

Comment: Posted [an answer with explanations and a demo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56253006/3832970).

Answer (score 3):

How would one know in `I said 'this isn't incomplete but I was wrong.` the quoted part should end after `incomplete`. Isn't that impossible with ordinary means.

Assuming you deal with single line strings, my rather simple idea would be

```
\B'(.*?)'\B|\B'(.*[^'\s])
```

and replace with `'$1$2'`. See [this demo at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/qTTVIA/2).

The idea is

- `\B'(.*?)'\B` to consume any "complete" quotes that start from a single quote that is not preceded by a *word character* (`\B` *non word boundary*) until a single quote that is not followed by a word character and capture the content to `$1`.
- `\B'(.*[^'\s])` Look for the remaining `'` that are not preceded by a word character and capture anything until the last character that is not a white space `\s` or single quote to `$2`.
- Finally replace already complete `$1` and uncomplete `$2` with `'$1$2'`. It's kind of [this idea](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-best-trick.html#thetrick).

Far from perfect but hope a bit of help.

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
preg_match("~^(?:[^']|\b'\b)*(?!\b'\b)'(?:[^']|\b'\b)*$~", $s)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/tHxncs/2)

**Regex details**

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:[^']|\b'\b)*` - 0 or more repetitions of any char but `'` or any `'` enclosed with word chars
- `(?!\b'\b)'` -  a `'` not enclosed with word chars
- `(?:[^']|\b'\b)*` - 0 or more repetitions of any char but `'` or any `'` enclosed with word chars
- `$` - end of string.

[Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(%3F%3A%5B%5E'%5D%7C%5Cb'%5Cb)*(%3F!%5Cb'%5Cb)'(%3F%3A%5B%5E'%5D%7C%5Cb'%5Cb)*%24):

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about regex, but you could try and check a string that has :

- An even number of apostrophes
- Starts with one
- Ends with one

All those conditions together should work.

Answer (score 0):

you can add modifiers "global" or "multiline" to regexp. Quote may be closed at next line too.